# Repeat last action in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to know if there is a shortcut in Google Docs Spreadsheets for repeating the last action, like <kbd>F4</kbd> in MS Office.

I found that there was no shortcut for this on Google Forums but the post were from 2009, so I don’t know if there is *now* the shortcut I’m looking for.

Answer (score 22):

Apparently Google decided to add the <kbd>F4</kbd> functionality for Google Sheets since the OP posted this question.

I know it works for inserting/removing rows at least.

Comment: Sadly, it's not there yet in Docs.

Comment: I'm still getting the "There are no changes to redo." alert. I tried pressing F4 or CTRL+Y  after inserting or removing a row

Comment: @elunicotomas I just tried right clicking on a row in Sheets and inserting a new row, then when I hit F4 it inserts another one... it does seem to work in that case :-)

Comment: @HighlyIrregular yep, it's working now, maybe I did something wrong:P

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> for MacOS

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> on Linux Firefox at least

I just discovered this, and tested it on text input, text formatting and line insertion.

Comment: That seems to be the _redo_ command, which only lets you undo your previous undo command.

Comment: exactly as Vidar said

Comment: +1 Check again -- this answer works despite the down votes. Redo is CMD-Y and it repeats on a Mac.

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal **CMD-Y** is the _redo_ command but also **Repeat Last Action**.

Comment: Perhaps this will clear confusion, but effectively **CMD-Y** seems to work as follows: **IF** there is something to Redo: perform **Redo**. **ELSE**: perform **Repeat Last Action**